# ChatBot Telegram: Múltiplas conversas e Confusão nas mensagens

Tags: java, chatbot, telegram

Estou fazendo um chatbot em java no telegram, tudo flui normalmente, mas quando mais de uma pessoa começa a interagir com o bot, ele para de funcionar para os outros usuários, e só funciona para um. tentei diversas formas, mas não consegui arrumar isso. segue abaixo o código, não sabia qual parte do código seria importante para isso, então enviei todo:

```
public class MainBOT extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

HashMap<Long, String> interacoes = new HashMap<Long, String>();
String contexto = "inicio";
String acao = "";
Prestador p = new Prestador("", "", "");

@Override
public String getBotUsername() {
    return "PegraoAlegriaBot";
}

public void enviarMensagem(long idTelegram, String mensagem) {
    // Mensagem a ser enviada
    SendMessage send = new SendMessage();
    send.setChatId(idTelegram);
    send.setText(mensagem);

    try {
        execute(send);
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpdateReceived(Update u) {
    // Dados da mensagem recebida pelo bot
    String nome = u.getMessage().getFrom().getFirstName();
    long idTelegram = u.getMessage().getChatId();
    String mensagem = u.getMessage().getText();

    System.out.println("Contexto: " + contexto);
    System.out.println("Mensagem: " + mensagem);

    if (contexto == "inicio" || mensagem.contains("menu inicial")) {
        System.out.println("Entrou inicio");
        SendMessage send = new SendMessage();
        send.setChatId(idTelegram);
        send.setText(nome + ", seja bem vindo ao Pregão de Serviços. Selecione uma opção:");

        ReplyKeyboardMarkup keyboardMarkup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
        List<KeyboardRow> keyboard = new ArrayList<>();

        KeyboardRow row = new KeyboardRow();
        row.add("Menu Serviço");
        keyboard.add(row);

        row = new KeyboardRow();
        row.add("Menu Prestador");
        keyboard.add(row);

        keyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboard);
        keyboardMarkup.setResizeKeyboard(true);
        send.setReplyMarkup(keyboardMarkup);

        try {
            execute(send); // Sending our message object to user
            contexto = "";
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (mensagem.contains("Menu Prestador") || contexto.contains("Menu Prestador")) {
        System.out.println("Entrou prestador");
        SendMessage send = new SendMessage();
        send.setChatId(idTelegram);
        System.out.println(acao);
        send.setText(nome + ", o que deseja fazer com relação a prestadores? Selecione uma opção:");

        ReplyKeyboardMarkup keyboardMarkup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
        List<KeyboardRow> keyboard = new ArrayList<>();

        KeyboardRow row = new KeyboardRow();
        row.add("Cadastrar prestador");
        keyboard.add(row);

        row = new KeyboardRow();
        row.add("Listar prestadores");
        keyboard.add(row);

        row = new KeyboardRow();
        row.add("Voltar ao menu inicial");
        keyboard.add(row);

        keyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboard);
        keyboardMarkup.setResizeKeyboard(true);
        send.setReplyMarkup(keyboardMarkup);

        try {
            execute(send); // Sending our message object to user
            contexto = "";
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (mensagem.contains("Listar prestadores")) {
        try {
            mensagem = listarPrestador();
            System.out.println(mensagem);
            enviarMensagem(idTelegram, mensagem);
            contexto = "";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            mensagem = "Erro ao recuperar prestadores!";
        }
    } else if (mensagem.contains("Cadastrar prestador")) {
        contexto = "prestador nome";
        mensagem = "Vamos começar? Primeiro eu preciso do nome do prestador.";
        enviarMensagem(idTelegram, mensagem);
    } else if (contexto.contains("prestador nome")) {
        p.setNome(mensagem);
        contexto = "prestador email";
        mensagem = "Agora eu preciso do email do prestador.";
        enviarMensagem(idTelegram, mensagem);
    } else if (contexto.contains("prestador email")) {
        p.setEmail(mensagem);
        contexto = "prestador telefone";
        mensagem = "Agora eu preciso do telefone do prestador, no formato (99) 99999-9999.";
        enviarMensagem(idTelegram, mensagem);
    } else if (contexto.contains("prestador telefone")) {
        p.setTelefone(mensagem);
        DAOPrestador daoP = new DAOPrestador();
        try {
            daoP.inserir(p);
            mensagem = "Prestador cadastrado com sucesso!";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mensagem = "Erro no cadastro do prestador.";
        }
        enviarMensagem(idTelegram, mensagem);
        contexto = "Menu Prestador";
    }   

}

private String listarPrestador() throws SQLException{
    String resposta = "";
    DAOPrestador daoP = new DAOPrestador();
    ArrayList<Prestador> prests = daoP.pesquisarTodos();
    if (prests.size() == 0) {
        resposta = "Não existem prestadores cadastrados\n";
    } else {
        resposta = "Lista de prestadores cadastrados:\n";
        for (Prestador prest : prests) {
            resposta = resposta + "Nome: " + prest.getNome() + " E-mail: " + prest.getEmail() + "\n";
        }
    }
    return resposta;
}

@Override
public String getBotToken() {
    // Token gerado na criacao do bot
    return "";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApiContextInitializer.init();
    TelegramBotsApi telegramBot = new TelegramBotsApi();
    MainBOT bot = new MainBOT();
    Date data = new Date();
    System.out.println(data);

    try {
        telegramBot.registerBot(bot);
    } catch (TelegramApiRequestException e) {
        System.out.println("Erro no Bot");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

eu fiz uma alteração no metódo enviarMensagem, e assim consegui ter +1 conversa ao mesmo tempo (não testei para mais de 2) entretanto, ainda assim continua com um bug que ele utiliza a resposta de outro usuário.

exemplo:
ele pergunta

> nome
>   email
>   número

usuario 1 responde o nome, ai pro usuario 2 ele ja nao pede o nome e sim o email, e a próxima pergunta pro usuario 1 ele pede o número, e o usuario 2 fica sem nada ou buga. (e vice-versa).

codigo abaixo alterado "enviarMensagem":

```
public synchronized void enviarMensagem(long idTelegram,, String s) {
    SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
    sendMessage.enableMarkdown(true);
    sendMessage.setChatId(cidTelegram);
    sendMessage.setText(s);
    try {
        sendMessage(sendMessage);
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema parece estar na gestão do estado da aplicação. Você tem só uma instância do objeto `MainBOT` que tem um atributo chamado `contexto`.

O valor desse atributo vai ser compartilhado por todos os usuários causando os problemas que você está relatando. Você precisa criar uma solução para identificar o contexto para cada usuário.

Pelo código que você mandou, parece possível identificar o usuário baseado no que você chama de `idTelegram`. Você poderia criar um `Map` onde a chave é o `idTelegram` e o valor é um objeto com o estado desse chat.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, vou testar essas modificações.